# ant target exec fails, while running command on shell is sucsessful

Tags: c, ant, compilation

I got a build environment running for different target platforms and host platforms, using ant to do the main work.
For one target platform (Qualcomm's BREW MP, native C/C++), I need to execute the compilation with this ant target:

```
<target name="build.brew.target" if="${cfg.build.brew}" depends="brew.clean">
  <exec dir="${src.cpp.brew}/brew" executable="cs-make" failonerror="true" newenvironment="false">
    <env key="PATH" value="${env.PATH}" />
    <arg line="-f brew.mak" />
  </exec>
...
</target>
```

cs-make is a make utility from the BREW SDK and runs the build, that is defined in the makefile (brew.mak).
ant returns with an error when executing from cmd prompt (Win7/64), say

```
ant build.brew.target
```

ant prints out an error reported by cl.exe (part of Visual Studio 2010 Express):

```
 [exec] "C:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BREWMP~1/TOOLSE~1.246/bin/cifc.exe"  -bar Win32_Debug/../res/brew.bar -IC:\Dev\lib\cpp\libspeex\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/inc -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/../inc -I../inc -I../../common -IC:\Dev\ignore\BOOST_~1 -IWin32_Debug ../res/brew.car
 [exec] "C:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BREWMP~1/TOOLSE~1.246/bin/cifc.exe"  -bar Win32_Debug/../res/brew.bar -IC:\Dev\lib\cpp\libspeex\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/inc -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/../inc -I../inc -I../../common -IC:\Dev\ignore\BOOST_~1 -IWin32_Debug -M ../res/brew.car > Win32_Debug/../res/brew.bar.dep
 [exec] if exist Win32_Debug/../res/brew.bar (copy /b /v Win32_Debug\..\res\brew.bar +,,Win32_Debug\..\res\brew.bar>nul) else (echo on>Win32_Debug/../res/brew.bar)
 [exec] "C:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BREWMP~1/TOOLSE~1.246/bin/cifc.exe"  -IC:\Dev\lib\cpp\libspeex\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/inc -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/../inc -I../inc -I../../common -IC:\Dev\ignore\BOOST_~1 -IWin32_Debug ../res/brew.cif -pre Win32_Debug/brew.clif -M > Win32_Debug/brew.clif.dep
 [exec] "C:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BREWMP~1/TOOLSE~1.246/bin/cifc.exe"  -IC:\Dev\lib\cpp\libspeex\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/inc -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/../inc -I../inc -I../../common -IC:\Dev\ignore\BOOST_~1 -IWin32_Debug ../res/brew.cif -pre Win32_Debug/brew.clif
 [exec] "C:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BREWMP~1/TOOLSE~1.246/bin/cifc.exe"   -mod brew -mif Win32_Debug/brew.mif Win32_Debug/brew.clif


 [exec] cs-make: *** [Win32_Debug/AEEAppGen.o] Error -1073741515


 [exec] "c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC//bin/cl.exe" -nologo -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -MTd -Z7 -EHsc -GS -Zl -RTC1 -Od -Ob1 -W3 -WX -wd4244 -wd4146 -wd4005 -wd4355 -c     -DAEE_SIMULATOR -D_DEBUG -D_DEBUG -DAEE_SIMULATOR  -IC:\Dev\lib\cpp\libspeex\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/inc -IC:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/../inc -I../inc -I../../common -IC:\Dev\ignore\BOOST_~1 -IWin32_Debug -I"c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC//Include" -I"c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC//PlatformSDK/Include" -FoWin32_Debug/AEEAppGen.o C:/PROGRA~1/Qualcomm/BrewMPSDK/Platforms/BREW4/sdk/src/AEEAppGen.c

BUILD FAILED
C:\Dev\brew.xml:27: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Dev\brew.xml:43: exec returned: 2
```

I can't find anything about error -1073741515, so I have no idea what is the trouble about. BUT: If I run the same command (in the same cmd window as my ant call before), everything works fine.

```
cs-make -f brew.mak
```

My first thought was - and stays my best bet - that it must have to do with my environment. For this, I added the `newenvironment="false"` to my exec line. With no success.
Any hint would be welcome...

Comment: try adding `-verbose` or `-debug` to your ant call to see if you get more useful information about why `exec` is failing

Comment: I did, but there is hardly more to see. Really, the only thing that comes along is the stack trace of ant. I also tried with `output="somefile.log"` parameter for exec target, but the output is the same as on screen. It is not an ant error, the error message is thrown by the cs-make.exe, but I can't figure out what is means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a question of too late for work. After I first encountered this error, I thought it must be the the %PATH% or other environment variable. So I added this line:

```
<env key="PATH" value="${env.PATH}" />
```

I got this copied from elsewhere within my project, but did not cross check, if it holds the correct %PATH% for my environment.
As it did not work, I googled and found the parameter `newenvironment="false"` for the exec target and added it - but as the above mentioned line within the target did not hold the correct env.PATH value, it went wrong.

This works for me:

```
<target name="build.brew.target" if="${cfg.build.brew}" depends="brew.clean">
  <exec dir="${src.cpp.brew}/brew" executable="cs-make" failonerror="true" newenvironment="false">
    <arg line="-f brew.mak" />
  </exec>
  ...
</target>
```